# Как переписать функцию на node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Делаю интернет магазин. У меня была бд в разных json файлах по названию бренда.
Была функция запроса на сервер и на сервере была функция которая отвечала нужным json файлом.
Сейчас хочу сделать чтобы вся бд была в одном csv файле и подключаться через ноду к mysql.
Но я даже элементарно функцию ответа переписать не могу, чтобы например просто ответить с сервера Hello, World.
После каких либо изменений в файле сервера, ничего не происходит, даже пробовал удалять файл, всё равно работает как раньше. В чём может быть проблема?

функция запроса

```
<a href="list.html" onclick="loadBrand('/js/data/adidasOriginals.json')">adidas Originals</a>
```

```
function loadBrand(x) {

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhr.open('GET', x, false);

      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;


        if (xhr.status != 200) {
          // обработать ошибку
          alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
        } else {
          try {
            brand = xhr.responseText;
          } catch (e) {
            alert("Некорректный ответ " + e.message);
          }
            sessionStorage.setItem("brand", brand);
        }

      }

      xhr.send();

    }
```

функция ответа

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var static = require('node-static');
var file = new static.Server('.', {
    cache: 0
});

function accept(req, res) {
    if (req.url == '/js/data/СASIO.json' || req.url == '/js/data/adidasOriginals.json' ||
        req.url == '/js/data/AlphaIndistries.json' || req.url == '/js/data/BookPublishers.json' ||
        req.url == '/js/data/BubbleGum.json' || req.url == '/js/data/C.P.Company.json' ||
        req.url == '/js/data/CalvinKleinJeans.json' || req.url == '/js/data/CanadaGoose.json' ||
        req.url == '/js/data/ChampionReverseWeave.json' || req.url == '/js/data/CommedesGarconsSHIRT.json' ||
        req.url == '/js/data/Converse.json' || req.url == '/js/data/Crocs.json' ||
        req.url == '/js/data/DanielWellington.json' || req.url == '/js/data/Dr.Martens.json' ||
        req.url == '/js/data/Edwin.json' || req.url == '/js/data/Evisu.json' ||
        req.url == '/js/data/Hackett.json' || req.url == '/js/data/HellyHansen.json' ||
        req.url == '/js/data/Lacoste.json' || req.url == '/js/data/Levis.json' ||
        req.url == '/js/data/LigneBlanche.json' || req.url == '/js/data/MA.Strum.json' ||
        req.url == '/js/data/maharishi.json' || req.url == '/js/data/MaisonKitsune.json' ||
        req.url == '/js/data/MARKET.json' || req.url == '/js/data/Master-piece.json' ||
        req.url == '/js/data/MedicomToy.json' || req.url == '/js/data/MKIMiyuki-Zoku.json' ||
        req.url == '/js/data/MSGM.json' || req.url == '/js/data/Napapijri.json' ||
        req.url == '/js/data/NativeUnion.json' || req.url == '/js/data/NewBalance.json' ||
        req.url == '/js/data/Nike.json' || req.url == '/js/data/NorseProjects.json' ||
        req.url == '/js/data/Oakley.json' || req.url == '/js/data/PeacefulHooligan.json' ||
        req.url == '/js/data/PoloRalphLauren.json' || req.url == '/js/data/Porter-Yoshida&Co.json' ||
        req.url == '/js/data/Puma.json' || req.url == '/js/data/RAINS.json' ||
        req.url == '/js/data/Ray-Ban.json' || req.url == '/js/data/Reebok.json' ||
        req.url == '/js/data/Ripndip.json' || req.url == '/js/data/Sandqvist.json' ||
        req.url == '/js/data/Seiko.json' || req.url == '/js/data/StoneIsland.json' ||
        req.url == '/js/data/TheNorthFace.json' || req.url == '/js/data/thisisneverthat.json' ||
        req.url == '/js/data/Timberland.json' || req.url == '/js/data/Timex.json' ||
        req.url == '/js/data/TommyJeans.json' || req.url == '/js/data/uniformexperiment.json' ||
        req.url == '/js/data/UniversalWorks.json' || req.url == '/js/data/Vans.json' ||
        req.url == '/js/data/Victorinox.json' || req.url == '/js/data/Y-3.json' ||
        req.url == '/js/data/YEEZY.json' || req.url == '/js/data/All.json') {
        file.serve(req, res);

    }
}

// ------ запустить сервер -------

if (!module.parent) {
    http.createServer(accept).listen(8080);
} else {
    exports.accept = accept;
}
```

переписал функции, чтобы просто послать запрос и получить ответ текстом и вывести его в алерт

```
<a href="listBrand.html" onclick="bs('bs')">Новинки</a>
```

```
function bs(x) {

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhr.open('GET', x, false);

      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;


        if (xhr.status != 200) {
          // обработать ошибку
          alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
        } else {
          try {
            alert(xhr.responseText)
          } catch (e) {
            alert("Некорректный ответ " + e.message);
          }
        }

      }

      xhr.send();

    }
```

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var querystring = require('querystring');



function accept(req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {
'Content‐Type': 'text/plain',
'Cache‐Control': 'no‐cache'
});
res.end("OK");
}



http.createServer(accept).listen(8080);

console.log('Погнали')
```

перезапускаю сервер командой ctrl + c;

чищу кэш командой npm cache clean --force;

запускай файл командой node server.js;

выводится сообщение в консоли "Погнали", но ответ "OK" не выводится, выводится ошибка 404, потому что выполняется старая функция ответа

Comment: Какой ужас с `req.url ==`, вы бы про switch узнали)

Comment: да, спасибо, мне уже посоветовали на одном форуме, но я не работаю программистом, а только учусь, в моём случае главное чтоб работало

Comment: Проверьте, куда отправляется ваш запрос. 404 говорит о том, что адрес не найден. Или уточните, в каком месте вы получаете 404

Comment: switch с req.url не нужен.
нужно поместить все урлы в массив и проверять потом if (jsonUrlsArray.some(url => url === req.url)) { /* your logic */ }